# sending image buffer to the frontend and display

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, buffer

i am using mongodb as my database and node.js as a server. i managed to save image array as buffer data. can i send those buffer data to the front-end and display. is it faster than sending image URL s?,

Comment: hi i am testing this in my local machine. do u have any idea of sending image to the frontend as buffer data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store image in your own database and send It to the front-end, but It is not recommended if you don't have a strong enough server to process that buffer datas [as described here](https://www.datanamic.com/support/storeimagesinthedatabase.html).

Comment: hi TamTam thanks for replying me. i tested with single image buffer. i was able to send image data as a response to the frontend.  the response size was in bytes which is very small.  decoding that buffer in the frontend to create image will also take down my site slow?

Comment: I have worked with this kind of task, testing with single image or a video can have a good result with performance test. But imagine if you have to load a gallery, It will be a big problem to your server and your front-end will have to wait for the server to finish It job. Therefore your site will be slow.

Comment: hi TamTam i am researching to upload images into another cdn and save url's into the DB. do u have any ideas about how to do that with reasonable budget?

Comment: sorry for the late response, I recommend you to use **firebase** or **cloudinary**. They have free plan, well-written documents and that will be enough for your practice.